# Magento 2 how to change url of attribute filter layer navigation?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5

I want to change color=red instead of color=18.

I have change here : vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php we have getUrl() function

```
public function getUrl()
{
    $query = array(
        $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
        Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
    );
    return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
}
```

to

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $query = array(
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getLabel(),
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
        );
        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
    }
```

change $this->getLabel() filter stop working.

Comment: any helps ?????